# How to log "server exec time" = (latency - connect time)

Tags: jmeter

How can I log (by using sample_variables=...,...) jdbc/server exec time which we define as (latency - connect time)?

We would like to use the metric for a custom graph in the Jmeter Reporting module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=execTime
   ```

   See [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) user manual entry for more information
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which "exec time" you want to measure or put it at the same level as other JDBC Request samplers (see [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for details)

   Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.putObject('execTime', prev.getLatency() - prev.getConnectTime())
   ```

   it will subtract connect time from latency and store the value into `execTime` JMeter Variable
3. Now you should be able to follow instructions from [Generating customs graphs over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) JMeter user manual chapter